# Performance review based python script on yocto linux

Tags: python, linux, embedded, logstash, yocto

I need to develop the performance review based python script , here is the scenario.

- I need to send the logs to ElK (Elasticsearch, logstash , Kibana)
  from yocto linux but only when system resources are free enough
- So    what I need here a python script which continuously monitor the
  system performance and when system resources like CPU is less then 50% 
  start sending the logs and if CPU again goes  above 50% **PAUSE** the logging
- Now I am don't have idea we can pause any process with python
  or not? This is because I want this for logs so when its start
  again send the logs from where it stops last time

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Would be neat if you could supply us with some piece of code showing some effort of problem solving. Also I know from previous experiences that if you Google (or Bing, whicever is your poison) each individual problems that you describe there's example codes for almost all of them (I've done something similar in the past). Give that a go, post your code and explain where things go wrong and we can help you out : )

Comment: First thing , I am not a python developer so I need to do in python . I am going to start that stuff . I need to confirm from experts is the PAUSE thing is possible with python according to my requirement?  I check some of the links , https://github.com/josegonzalez/python-beaver ,https://github.com/josegonzalez/python-beaver

Comment: If you're not a Python developer, I'd suggest you either find one or learn Python or in fact, do the project in another language that you're familiar with. **regarding PAUSE**, that is a question we could answer here for you, certainly.. But your question is phrased in such a way that you're asking us to do the work for you which we can't/won't.

Comment: Requirement is here I need to write the in the python , not any other language. So I need to learn that :) ..... Sorry about asking way ... I said I need to develop which means I will going to it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all your requirements are possible in Python.
In fact it's possible in basically any language because you're not asking for cutting edge stuff, this is basic scripting.

### Sending logs to ES/Kibana

It's possible, Kibana, ES and Splunk all have public API's with good documentation on how to do it, so yes it's possible.

### Pausing a process in Linux

Yes, also possible. If it's a external process simply find the `PID` of your process and send `kill -STOP <PID>` which would stop the process, to resume the process, do `run kill -CONT <PID>`. If it's your own process that you want to pause, simply enter a sleep cycle in your code (simple example `while PAUSED: time.sleep(0.5)`.

Comment: I am going to start working on that and start learning python :)

Comment: @abaid778 Do so, it's a great and fast programming language. I wish you the best of luck and I suggest you either delete your question or give me or anyone a "Solved" status on a answer so this question doesn't get lost in the black sea of "never solved questions".